# Task state when mutex and/or semaphore not acquired

Tags: rtos

I have basic understanding of rtos and task states.

My query is when a task is unable to acquire mutex, in which particular state the task is moved to?
Also if task is unable to acquire binary semaphore, in which particular state the task is moved?

I am aware of SUSPEND and WAIT state. But not sure in mutex and semaphore case. I want to know the detailed understanding.

Comment: There isn't any universal law for this.  Each RTOS developer may implement things slightly different from the next.  Read the documentation for your RTOS (or look at the source code) to find the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a RTOS can have it own implementation. But generally there is mutex wait queue handled by the scheduler, when the task is unable to acquire a mutex it goes into the mutex wait queue.